# How to calculate route using viaPoints array

Tags: objective-c, skmaps

If I have a route calculated from point A to point B using the following code:

```
[SKRoutingService sharedInstance].routingDelegate = self;
[SKRoutingService sharedInstance].navigationDelegate = self;
[SKRoutingService sharedInstance].mapView = _mapView;
SKRouteSettings* route = [[SKRouteSettings alloc]init];
route.startCoordinate=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([Constants shared].location.x, [Constants shared].location.y);
route.destinationCoordinate=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([Constants shared].destination.x, [Constants shared].destination.y);
route.shouldBeRendered = YES;
SKNavigationSettings* navSettings = [SKNavigationSettings navigationSettings];
navSettings.navigationType=SKNavigationTypeSimulation;
navSettings.distanceFormat=SKDistanceFormatMilesFeet;

[SKRoutingService sharedInstance].mapView.settings.displayMode = SKMapDisplayMode2D;
[[SKRoutingService sharedInstance] calculateRoute:route];
```

And the above is all fine. Route will be calculated and display with no problem.
But how do I add a viaPoint to the already calculated route?
Do I need to clear the already created one and calculate new one, or somehow recalculate the existing one with another point added.

And another question, how do I properly create a SKViaRoute object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to calculate a route with via points you need to populate the [viaPoints](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/ios/2.5.0/Classes/SKRouteSettings.html#//api/name/viaPoints) array in the routeSettings.

If you want to add or remove a via point from an already existing  route you want to use the [addViaPoint](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/ios/2.5.0/Classes/SKRoutingService.html#//api/name/addViaPoint:afterViaPointWithID:) / [removeViaPoint](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/ios/2.5.0/Classes/SKRoutingService.html#//api/name/removeViaPoint:) methods.

Comment: Hey Ando, How do I create an actual SKViaPoint object? Because something like SKViaPoint *viaPoint = [[SKViapoint alloc]init]; doesn't do the trick